# Need to export classes for NPM package

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules

I am building an NPM package and am looking for the best way to export my classes.

Right now, I am using this:

```
import {Swan} from './Swan';
import {Route, Router} from './Router';
import {View, TemplateView, IView} from './views';

export { Route, Router, Swan, View, TemplateView, IView };
```

This works. The only thing is, of course, each time I add a new class, I have to update the export statement.

Is there a way to export all the classes in all the files I specify without having to update the export statement here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is there a way to export all the classes in all the files I specify without having to update the export statement here?

There is no automatic "export everything" or export all classes in Javascript.

---

But, you could change how you define your classes so they are part of an internal object and you just export that object.

```
 const myExports = {
      TemplateView: class TemplateView {
          ...
      },
      iView: class iView {
         ...
      }

 };

 export default myExports;
```

When you add a new class to this structure, it automatically becomes part of the exports.

---

On the other hand, I personally don't see what the big deal is to maintain the export list when you add a new item to the module that you want exported. Exports are SUPPOSED to be a thoughtful list of things that only contains the items that need to be exported and does not contain other functions used locally as part of the implementation. The only way that it can be a thoughtful list is if it's not automatic.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Right now I have files with multiple exports. Looks like I would have to keep doing the same thing I am for all the items that can't be default exported, right?

Comment: @LeeLoftiss - Yep.  I personally don't see what the big deal is to maintain the export list when you add a new item to the module that you want exported.  Exports are SUPPOSED to be a thoughtful list of things that only contains the items that need to be exported and does not contain other functions used locally as part of the implementation.  The only way that it can be a thoughtful list is if it's not automatic.